Hilbert's Nullstellensatz in modern algebraic geometry
Most reading this are probably already aware of the statement of the Nullstellensatz, but for completeness I'll state it (or at least one version of it) once more:
Theorem Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. If $I\subset k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is an ideal, then $$I(Z(I))=\sqrt{I}.$$ Thus, the correspondences $I\mapsto Z(I)$ and $X\mapsto I(X)$ induce a bijection between the collection of algebraic subsets of $\mathbb A_k^n$ and radical ideals of $k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$.
I find the statement very fascinating and I am also aware of the generalization of the theorem using Jacobson rings; see, for example Eisenbud: Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry, Theorem 4.19. Thus we've established a fundamental connection between algebra and geometry. However this still leaves me wanting more. As I'm only really getting into algebraic geometry, maybe I'm reaching for more in vain. So, what does the Nullstellensatz tell us in terms of ''modern'' algebraic geometry, say sheaves and schemes? Is there even anything to be deduced from the Nullstellensatz in sheaf- or scheme theory, or are the implications of the theorem contained in the theory of varieties?

A few generalisations are discussed here. For the context with schemes, see for example this post.

A topological space $X$ is called Jacobson if the set of closed points $X_0$ is very dense in $X$, which means that for any closed subset $C \subset X$, $X_0 \cap C$ is dense in $C$. A scheme is called Jacobson if its underlying topological space is Jacobson. One way to state a generalization of the Nullstellensatz is the following:
Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism locally of finite type and suppose that $Y$ is a Jacobson scheme, then:

$X$ is Jacobson
$f$ maps closed points to closed points
For all closed points $x \in X$, the field extension $\kappa(x)/\kappa(f(x))$ is finite.

One can easily deduce the various forms of the classical Nullstellensatz (and Zariski's lemma) from this.
One consequence of this is that over an algebraically closed field $k$ and a $k$-scheme $X$ locally of finite type over $X$, $k$-rational points of $X$ are the same as closed points of $X$. More generally, let $k$ be a perfect field with algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ and absolute Galois group $G=\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$, then closed points of a $k$-scheme $X$ that is locally of finite type over $k$ correspond to $G$-orbits of $X(\overline{k})$. This can also be deduced from the above theorem.

Let $k$ be algebraically closed, $X=\mathbb{A}^n_k$, $Y=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$. $Y$ is trivially Jacobson, and $X\to Y$ of finite type, so your theorem applied to $X\to Y$ shows affine space is Jacobson and that $\kappa(x)/k$ is finite for all closed $x$ i.e. $k\to\kappa(x)$ is an isomorphism and then the closed points of $X$ can be identified with the classical affine space $k^n$. Great, that's the weak Nullstellensatz. How does one move to the strong form, "$J\mapsto V(J)$ is a bijective order-reversing correspondence between radical ideals and closed subspaces"?

@FShrike I guess I was imprecise a little bit. From the fact that $\Bbb A_k^n$ is Jacobson, we get that closed subspaces of $k^n$ are in canonical (and inclusion-preserving) bijection with closed subspaces of $\Bbb A_k^n$ (as a scheme). To conclude from there, we need the "formal Nullstellensatz" which holds for any affine scheme and says that radical ideals correspond to closed subsets.

But showing that $\Bbb A_k^n$ is Jacobson is harder than showing the formal Nullstellensatz, that's why I felt justified in saying that the strong Nullstellensatz follows from the the theorem about Jaconson schemes above.
